# Python 3.4 Winrandom compiling error

Tags: python, windows, gcc

I am trying to compile winrandom and got the followint error.
Please help - what could be the reason?

```
c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\winrandom.o bui
ld\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\winrandom.def -LC:\Python34\libs -LC:\Python34\PCb
uild -lCrypt32 -lpython34 -lmsvcr100 -o build\lib.win32-3.4\winrandom.pyd
Cannot export PyInit_winrandom: symbol not defined
build\temp.win32-3.4\Release\src\winrandom.o:winrandom.c:(.text+0x437): undefine
d reference to `Py_InitModule'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'c:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom) calls [`CryptGenRandom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379942) to generate random data using the [`PROV_RSA_FULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387448) provider.

Answer (score 0):

`Py_InitModule` is no longer used in Python 3.X, the package you downloaded is probably for Python 2.X. That is where you issue lies. Try finding a version that is meant for Python 3.X

Comment: @Vcitor, why would it matter? The same Windows API is available as `os.urandom`. If you have a dependency on `winrandom`, surely you could mock up a version that calls `os.urandom`.